# LSTM having a systematic offset between predictions and ground truth

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

Currently i think i'm experiencing a systematic offset in a LSTM model, between the predictions and the ground truth values. What's the best approach to continue further from now on?

The model architecture, along with the predictions & ground truth values are shown below. This is a regression problem where the historical data of the target plus 5 other correlated features `X` are used to predict the target `y`. Currently the input sequence `n_input` is of length 256, where the output sequence `n_out` is one. Simplified, the previous 256 points are used to predict the next target value.

`X` is normalized. The mean squared error is used as the loss function. Adam with a cosine annealing learning rate is used as the optimizer (`min_lr=1e-7`, `max_lr=6e-2`).

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
cu_dnnlstm_8 (CuDNNLSTM)     (None, 256)               270336    
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_11 (Batc (None, 256)               1024      
_________________________________________________________________
leaky_re_lu_11 (LeakyReLU)   (None, 256)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_11 (Dropout)         (None, 256)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_11 (Dense)             (None, 1)                 257       
=================================================================
Total params: 271,617
Trainable params: 271,105
Non-trainable params: 512
_________________________________________________________________
```

Increasing the node size in the LSTM layer, adding more LSTM layers (with `return_sequences=True`) or adding dense layers after the LSTM layer(s) only seems to lower the accuracy. Any advice would be appreciated.

[image]

Additional information on the image. The y-axis is a value, x-axis is the time (in days). NaNs have been replaced with zero, because the ground truth value in this case can never reach zero. That's why the odd outliers are in the data.

**Edit:**
I made some changes to the model, which increased accuracy. The architecture is the same, however the features used have changed. Currently only the historical data of the target sequence itself is used as a feature. Along with this, `n_input` got changed so `128`. Switched `Adam` for `SGD`, mean squared error with the mean absolute error and finally the NaNs have been interpolated instead of being replaced with 0.

One step ahead predictions on the validation set look fine:

[image]

However, the offset on the validation set remains:

[image]

It might be worth noting that this offset also appears on the train set for x < ~430:
[image]

Comment: Your seq-length is too large, did you try another variant of this? What your data-size?

Comment: The total dataset is 1427 timesteps, split into 50% train, 20% val and 30% test. I'll go try a smaller input sequence now, will post updates as soon as i got them.

Comment: Alright so here is the update. Forward filling all NaNs instead of replacing them with 0 increased the accuracy by relatively a lot. Removing all other features but the historical sequence of the target also helped. For the input sequence length, longer gives better results. However, the offset still remains and currently is about +15% from the ground truth, while the shape of the predictions look exactly in agreement with the ground truth.

Comment: I presume you might be experiencing a problem similar to the one described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48034625/keras-lstm-predicted-timeseries-squashed-and-shifted/48050810#48050810) answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It looks like your model is overfitting and is simply always returning the value from the last timestep as a prediction. Your dataset is probably too small to have a model with this amount of parameters converge. You'll need to resort to techniques that combat overfitting: agressive dropout, adding more data, or try simpler, less overparameterized methods.

**This phenomenon (LSTMs returning a shifted version of the input) has been a recurring theme in many stackoverflow questions.** The answers there might contain some useful information:

[LSTM Sequence Prediction in Keras just outputs last step in the input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48286122/lstm-sequence-prediction-in-keras-just-outputs-last-step-in-the-input)

[LSTM model just repeats the past in forecasting time series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50599712/lstm-model-just-repeats-the-past-in-forecasting-time-series)

[LSTM NN produces “shifted” forecast (low quality result)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/338923/lstm-nn-produces-shifted-forecast-low-quality-result)

[Keras network producing inverse predictions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54189142/keras-network-producing-inverse-predictions)

[Stock price predictions of keras multilayer LSTM model converge to a constant value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51618251/stock-price-predictions-of-keras-multilayer-lstm-model-converge-to-a-constant-va/51723013#51723013)

[Keras LSTM predicted timeseries squashed and shifted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48034625/keras-lstm-predicted-timeseries-squashed-and-shifted/48050810#48050810)

[LSTM Time series shifted predictions on stock market close price](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60150501/lstm-time-series-shifted-predictions-on-stock-market-close-price)

[Interesting results from LSTM RNN : lagged results for train and validation data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53199099/interesting-results-from-lstm-rnn-lagged-results-for-train-and-validation-data)

Finally, be aware that, depending on the nature of your dataset, there simply might be no pattern to be discovered in your data at all. You see this a lot with people trying to predict the stock market with LSTMs (there is a question on stackoverflow on how to predict the lottery numbers).

Comment: Thank you very much, it was kind of hard to find this answer. Almost all tutorials, blogs and papers focus on one step ahead forecasting and simply ignore the problems with multi steps ahead forecasting.

To anyone else having this problem: it seems like CNNs give more promising results.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is much simpler than we thought...
I saw multiple people saying this is due to overfitting and datasize. Some other people stated this is due to rescaling.
After several try, I found the solution: **Try to do detrending before feed the data to RNN.**
For example, you can do a simple degree-2 polynomial fitting of the data which will give you a polynomial formula. And it is possible to reduce the each data value corresponding to the formula value. Then we got a new dataset and we can feed it to the LSTM, after prediction we can just add the trend back to the result and the results should look better.