# LSTM Time series shifted predictions on stock market close price

Tags: keras, time-series

I have developed a RNN system to predict the stock market close price based on several features. I removed the close price from the X and moved it to Y. I also made a shift on Y and `dropna()` to make sure that all features of day X(t) is equals to Y(t+future_days). Thus means that the features for today will predict the close price of today plus future_days.

From the images bellow, the first future_days = 20 and the second future_days = 5. The prediction is shifted the number of future_days in each image. I am ploting the predictions and close, where close is equals to Y_test, which is also shifted future_days. Thus, I was expecting that Y_Test would be the same of prediction and the data would not be shifted in time.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [LSTM having a systematic offset between predictions and ground truth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54368686/lstm-having-a-systematic-offset-between-predictions-and-ground-truth)

Comment: Well, it does not really solve the problem but make sense.